# Play framework 2.5 scala i18n

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, twirl

I've followed the documentation in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaI18N and translations inside controllers works fine.
However, I need translations in Twirl templates.
With `implicit messages` and/or using `Messages("test.testing")` I get the following error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
```

My controller:

```
class HomeController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def updateLocale(lang: String) = Action { implicit request =>
    printf(request.headers.get("Accept-Language").getOrElse("niente"))
    printf(Messages("test.testing"))
    Ok(views.html.index(Messages("test.testing")))
  }
```

This also makes me doubt how can I allow changing the language in the application...

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Messages` with injected `messagesApi`:

```scala
class HomeController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi)
                   extends Controller with I18nSupport {

      def updateLocale(lang: String): EssentialAction = Action {
        implicit request =>
          printf(request.headers.get("Accept-Language").getOrElse("niente"))
          printf(messagesApi("test.testing"))
          Ok(views.html.index(messagesApi("test.testing")))
      }
    }
```

Comment: After some time I realized I was adding implicit messages in the wrong template. I've also changed my controller from Messages to messagesApi as you mentioned.
I've accepted this answer. Thank you